# How to access JSON siblings "keys"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, key-value

I have a `json` stracture like:

```
     var abraham = {

                   wife:{
                    name:"Sarah"
                        },

                  first_born:{
                    name: "Isaac"
                    wife:"Rebekkah",
                    child:"Jacob"

                      },
```

Now i have a new "key" that I want its "value" to be the value of one of its siblings. Someyhing like:

```
abraham_first_born_name:  first_born.name, //I get Errors:
```

I tried:

```
abraham_first_born_name:  first_born.name, //Error: first_born.name undefined
abraham_daughter_in_law: first_born.wife, //Error: first_born.wife undefined
abraham_grand_child:     first_born.child,  ////Error: first_born.child undefined
```

And tried:

```
abraham_first_born_name:  this.first_born.name, //Error: this.first_born.name undefined
abraham_daughter_in_law: this.first_born.wife, //Error: this.first_born.wife undefined
abraham_grand_child:     this.first_born.child,  ////Error: this.first_born.child undefined
```

And Lastly tried:

```
abraham_first_born_name:  $(this).first_born.name, //Error: $(this).first_born.name undefined
abraham_daughter_in_law: $(this).first_born.wife, //Error: $(this).first_born.wife undefined
abraham_grand_child:     $(this).this.first_born.child,  ////Error: $(this).first_born.child undefined    
}
```

How can I access the **data** of a `key` such as `abraham_first_born_name` to be assigned as the value of, `first_born.name`.... which is a fellow sibling `key`'s??

Please note that before asking this questin I visited the google of hours and tried: [How to access Json key inside a json key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353000/how-to-access-json-key-inside-a-json-key) and [json sibling data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016304/json-sibling-data) and [Getting json sibling data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510504/getting-json-sibling-data) and [How to access key itself using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942911/how-to-access-key-itself-using-javascript) and [Accessing siblings in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834872/accessing-siblings-in-jquery) and [accessing a siblings in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13045295/accessing-a-siblings-in-jquery)

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: You cannot do that in JavaScript object literals. You have to add the properties in separate statements.

Comment: How??... any suggestion???

Comment: And [one another example](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/5gcjv64r/) if you want to have up-to-date value like in Explosion Pills's answer, but want to be able to call `JSON.stringify` on `abraham`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use separate statements:

```
 var abraham = {

               wife:{
                name:"Sarah"
                    },

              first_born:{
                name: "Isaac"
                wife:"Rebekkah",
                child:"Jacob"

                  }
 };

 abraham.abraham_first_born_name = abraham.first_born.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create), but it would be a little verbose.

```
var abraham = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
    wife: {value: {name: "Sarah"}},
    first_born: {value: {name: "Isaac"}},
    abraham_first_born_name: {
        get: function () {
            return this.first_born.name;
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n4xqbjdo/